# ParsleyJS required and data-parsley-required

Tags: javascript, required, parsley.js

I have to use required='' on some fields, and then I use data-parsley-required on others. The parsleyJS is applying to the input fields that have required='' on them. Is there a way I can make the ParsleyJS only work on the fields that have the data-parsley-required on it?

Example:

I have the following fields

```
<input type="text" id="field1" data-parsley-required="true">

<input type="text" id="field2" required="">
```

Currently it parsley will try to validate both fields. How do i make it only validate if the field has data-parsley-required="true" on it?

Answer (score 3):

Parsley will turn off HTML5 validations, so it's not clear that this is what you actually want...

If you're sure that's what you want, you could exclude `[required]` fields:

```
<form data-parsley-excluded="[type=submit], [type=button], [type=reset], [type=hidden], [required]">
```

Note that if you have other validations on these required fields, this will turn off those validations as well...

Otherwise, you'll have to tweak the source code directly.

Comment: I can't do the exclusion like this, I need the required='' on all my fields, and then i have the data-parsley-required="true" on the ones I actually need validation on.